# Magento upgrade to 1.5 gives a 500 Internal server error

Tags: php, mysql, apache, magento

I'm trying to upgrade a magento webshop to version 1.5,
I however keep getting a 500 internal server error.
pretty much all answers google gives are related to chmodding,
well this isn't the problem, I've ensured that already.
Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: care to paste the errors produced in `apache/error.log` ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it needs PHP5 and your host is PHP4 by default? try adding this to the .htaccess file.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php
```